# Making Javascript Calls Synchronous

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback

I'm a bit newer to javascript and am having a hard time figuring out how to work the callbacks in some existing code.

Setup:
I have a util.js that contains a lot of helper functions like
function

```
getComments(packageId, successCallback, failCallback, userId)
```

and

```
function getActionMemo(packageId, versionId, successCallback, failCallback)
```

that return the results of an ajax call to the successCallback.

What I need to make, and what I'm struggling with, is a function that amasses the data of the helper functions and to make it more fun, I have a specific order I need to call the helper functions in because there are some data dependencies.

I can hack this by basically copying the code out of the helper functions into a new function and chaining the .done from the ajax call, but this seems like horrible practice.  Is there a cleaner way?

Thanks,
Erin

Answer (score 1):

Looks like promises could be a solution to your problem. Please read https://www.promisejs.org/

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of actions, these actions are stored in an array or into the html I suppose?

Create an index, starting at 0.

Then in your function you add 1 each time you start the function, select the new action and make your ajax call.

I met your scenario once and will detail the method I used if this doesn't help you.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, I recently took the first release of the Rogue game written for UNIX in C and rewrote it for javascript to work in a browser.  I used a technic called continuation to be able to wait for key entry by the user because in javascript the are no interrupts.

So I would have a piece of code like this:

```
void function f() {

  // ... first part

  ch = getchar();

  // ... second part

}
```

that would be transformed in

```
function f() {

  // ... first part

  var ch = getchar(f_cont1);

  return;
  // the execution stops here 

  function f_cont1 () {

    // ... second part
  }
}
```

the continuation is then stored to be reuse on a keypressed event.  With closures everything would be restarted where it stoped.